# Jasmine losing leaves

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health

My jasmine started (about a week ago) losing leaves.

I didn't pay it much attention at the time as it was only a few and since they were from the base, my cat could have knocked them down.

Now, though, they are falling en masse.

After some searching, I've found that It might be because it needed water, so I started giving it some (about a liter every 2 days)

The exact variety is : *Trachelospermum jasminoides*

The plant is on a balcony, in France, and gets its direct light from the west.

This plant is a gift, I don't usually tend to plants, and I don't know what I'm doing right or wrong.

Please help !

[image: Photo of the jasmine]
[image: Photo of lost leaves]
[image: Photos of leaves still on the plant]

Edit:

The plant continued to lose leaves, but the last ones that were falling were dry. As my pot has a drainage hole, I've opted to try and completely soak the dirt.